# Where to call notifyOnDataSetChanged

Tags: android, android-listview

In my code, I have two activities.

One is a list view activity, the other activity is being used to modify the data.
After the data is modified the user is returned to the list view activity.

My question is, where should I call notifyOnDataSetChanged?
Should I call it in the 'resume' method of the list view activity, so that the list is refreshed whenever it is displayed?

Or should I call it from the activity that modifies the data?

I would not know how to do the latter, as the adapter belongs to the list view activity, not to the other activity.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You should call it in the ListView Activity, the method basically queues the list to refresh so it should happen when you get back to the list. Also, as it is an adapter method, you can better guarantee that an instance of the list affected by the adapter is available.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how you handle your `Activities`, proabably call it in `onResume()` or some other method of your `ListViewActivity` so you will have access to your `adapter`.

However, another way would be to use `startActivityForResult()` in your `ListViewAcitvity` then call `notifyOnDataSetChanged()` in `onActivityResult()`, if that is an option you have